# Limit wordpress posts loop to continue onto another page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

Theres a site i did that on the home page, i created kind of like a **news** box type
of thing which is what the client wanted...

the posts bit im using to limit the posts on the index page is

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=4');
```

Now, this limits my posts to "4" or whatever number i want etc, when the user clicks on the 
"news" page button, it takes them to a page which has the full posts loop without the
`query_posts('posts_per_page=4');` which essentially shows them all the posts.

Now the problem is that, this person is posting A LOT now and the page now has a bunch of posts one after the other.

Is there a way to limit these to any number (that i choose) and show the rest of the posts on another page???

So essentially something that says

filter out 20 messages/excerpts for example, BUT after 20 show a "next" page or something like that?

is that possible? Because as it stands now, by years end this ONE page will have hundreds of posts.

ive looked around but not sure exactly what im looking for. This one came close (here on SO) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875895/wordpress-loop-show-limit-posts
And although its similar, i need a way to limit the posts on the page AND continue them on another page so that one page doesnt hold ALL the posts.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you mean pagination?

Answer (score 0):

just use WP's custom built pagination or a pagination plugin and that's it, not sure if this is what you mean though